# Getting TIFF Tags from an Image

Tags: java, image, tiff

I am trying to render a Tiff Image for extracting tags from it, here is what i have done till now:

```
ByteArraySeekableStream sStream= new ByteArraySeekableStream(imageByteArray);
ImageDecoder imgDecoder = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder("TIFF",sStream,null);
RenderedImage renderedImage = imgDecoder.decodeAsRenderedImage();
```

this seems to work fine for all positive scenarios, where as suppose if we have a TIFF image which has a missing tag in it.

for eg: If Image Length is missing, then i get the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: "Image Length", a required field, is not present in the TIFF file
```

but i do not want it to throw any exception, rather it should render the image with whatever TIFF tags are present.

Is there any other way of rendering a TIFF image? or is there a way of modifying the above code to achieve this requirement.

Comment: There's a reason `ImageLength` (or height) is a required field. Without it, the decoder don't know how many scanlines there are. You might be able to guess it, if your TIFF contains strips or tiles (but note that the last strip/tile isn't necessarily complete). Or if your TIFF is in a compression that contains redundant size information, like JPEG.

Comment: Missing length field is a sign that your TIFF is badly corrupt and probably wrong at other places. "it should render the image with whatever TIFF tags are present" sounds like a wrong idea.

Comment: @YvesDaoust i understand that it&amp;#39;s a bad idea to render it, but still its a part of my requirement that I need to validate whether the TIFF contains all the mandatory tags, and if it has some tag missing in it I need to set   a flag value corresponding to the missing tag.

Comment: By curiosity, is there a good explanation why a tag could be missing ? Are you validating a TIFF writer ? What's the benefit of knowing which tag is missing ???

Comment: The Java reader seems to be kind enough to give you an explanatory message, what more do you want ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust i get the TIFF images from another app which creates them, hence my requirement is to validate those images and if there is any missing tag in it, rather than throwing an exception I need to set a flag value corresponding to the missing tag/ tags.

A single Tiff image can have multiple missing tags and that case, I need to set multiple flag values corresponding to those 2 misisng tags.

Comment: @haraldK yes, but I need a way of rendering the image even if it does not contain all the mandatory tags in it.

Comment: https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/astifftagviewer.html

Comment: @YvesDaoust tifftagviewer can be used to validate an image manually, I need to identify it programmatically

Comment: @FAIZANAHMEDKHAN: if you can't find a Tiff tag analyzer in Java, you'll have to program it yourself.

Comment: @YvesDaoust okay, but let's keep aside the issue about the Tiff tag for a while, then my question would be is there any other way of rendering a TIFF image.?

Comment: @FAIZANAHMEDKHAN: no.

Comment: @YvesDaoust ok, tq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Tiff tags, u don't need to render the image first. If you render the image you will definitely get that exception if any tags are not proper.

Instead try this,

```
ByteArraySeekableStream sStream= new ByteArraySeekableStream(imageByteArray);
```

And get the Tiff directory from the stream instead of rendered image

```
TIFFDirectory tiffDr = new TIFFDirectory(sStream, 0)
```

From this you can get the Tiff tags, and then do the validations on the available tags in the image. Hope this helps.